# multiply a column by a calculated/measure of weight score in power bi dax

Tags: dax, weighted

I am trying to calculate the alphabetic grade based on the product of the column weight and the sum of count.

I had the following dax code:

```
weight = IF ( CONTAINSROW ( {"FirstName", "LastName", "Birthdate"}, table[columns]), 2, 1 )
```

after the above, I used it to multiply with the count

```
weightedvalue = table[count] * [weight]
```

But I get the following error:

```
A single value for column 'Weight' in table 'table' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.
```

Here is the sample table: count refers to the count of valid entries

```
columns  | count
FirstName|    25
LastName |    20
BirthDate|    10
```

after the weightedvalue, I use it as a denominator to find the percentage of valid scores.

Answer (score 0):

Your *weight* and *weightedvalue* formulas need a row context, so you have to enter them as **Calculated Columns**, not as **Measures**.

[image]